# How to solve "uninitialized value in scalar assignment" in Perl code?

Tags: perl, scalar

How would I solve the following in error in my code:

Use of uninitialized value in scalar assignment at faStat2 line 59.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

...

$~ = *OUTFILE; #This is the line it is complaining about
my $cmd = $0;
$cmd =~ s#.*/##;
```

Comment: Is `OUTFILE` open? Also `$~ = *OUTFILE` doesn't make any sense. Perhaps `$~ = 'OUTFILE'` (This doesn't make much sense either)?

Comment: Matt, in several of your questions you use `...`, for ease of use, can you please just provide a minimal example. It isn't relevant that other things occur, just the parts that cause the problem. Just makes it easier to run exactly what you do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`OUTFILE` should be in single quotes because without them it is a bareword and with the * in front of it it is seen as an item requiring scalar.  The code should look like:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

...

$~ = 'OUTFILE';
my $cmd = $0;
$cmd =~ s#.*/##;
```